# Window Function for First Instance in Repeating Time Periods

Tags: sql

I'm trying to translate the logic below into one or more SQL statements:

1. Find the first occurrence of a given event for a user
2. If the user has any additional events on that day or 30 days after, exclude those events. Keep only the first event.
3. 30 days after the original event, you may consider new events, but the original logic applies. Take only the first new event, then exclude any other in the 30 days after the second event.
4. Repeat for all events

Finding the first event is easy, as is excluding all events that occur in the 30 days after it. I'm having trouble trying to identify all the following windows/events after the first without looping or scripting.

My solution needs to support multiple RDBMS (MSSQL and Spark SQL at this time, potentially more), so the solution needs to be as close to standard SQL as possible, no platform-specific scripting. I also would like to avoid correlated subqueries if possible for performance reasons. But if that's the only way to solve the problem, I'm open to that as a solution.

Example data:

```
UserID  EventDate
1       2022-01-02 
1       2022-01-19 
1       2022-02-01 
1       2022-02-07 
1       2022-02-08 
1       2022-03-19 
2       2022-01-04
2       2022-01-05
2       2022-01-06
2       2022-02-22
```

Desired output:

```
UserID  EventDate   Include
1       2022-01-02  1
1       2022-01-19  0
1       2022-02-01  0
1       2022-02-07  1
1       2022-02-08  0
1       2022-03-19  1
2       2022-01-04  1
2       2022-01-05  0
2       2022-01-06  0
2       2022-02-22  1
```

Or:

```
UserID  EventDate
1       2022-01-02
1       2022-02-07
1       2022-03-19
2       2022-01-04
2       2022-02-22
```

Comment: tag your db please

Comment: @James As stated in the question, the solution can't be RDBMS specific. It needs to be as close to standard SQL as possible since the platform needs to support multiple backends.

Comment: With standar sql, you cannot get what you want. You likely need some window function, or some cte, or some kind of technique to relate non contiguous records (PLSQL, TSQL,...)

Comment: @James CTEs and windowing functions are standard SQL. CTEs have been ANSI standard SQL since at least [SQL:1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999#Common_table_expressions_and_recursive_queries). Windowing functions have been ANSI standard SQL since [SQL:2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003).

Comment: And then, why do exist different implementations depending on the vendor? Have you tried to perform the same CTE in sql server, oracle, db2 and mysql without any issue? Try and let me know after 

Comment: @James yes, our existing codebase makes extensive use of CTEs and windowing functions and produces the exact same result on SQL Server, Hive and Spark.

Comment: Can you show me it? In oracle, db2 and mysql too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on most DB.

```
drop table if exists #have;

create table #have
(
  UserID   [int]
, date     [date]
)
;

insert into #have
values
  (1, '2022-01-02')
, (1, '2022-01-19')
, (1, '2022-02-01')
, (1, '2022-02-07')
, (1, '2022-02-08')
, (1, '2022-03-19')
, (2, '2022-01-04')
, (2, '2022-01-05')
, (2, '2022-01-06')
, (2, '2022-02-22')
;

with c1 as
(
select *
     , isnull(datediff(day, lag(date, 1) over(partition by UserID 
                          order by date), date), 0) as diff 

from #have
)
,
c2 as
(
select *, sum(diff) over(partition by UserID 
                         order by date) as s
        , sum(diff) over(partition by UserID 
                         order by date) / 31 + 1 as thirty
from c1
)
,
c3 as
(
select UserID
     , min(date) as date
from c2
group by UserID, thirty
)

select * from c3 
order by UserID, date
;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this is perfect and a neat way to break down the problem. To break down how this works for anyone else reading, this calculates the days between the current date and last row's date. It then cumulatively sums the difference by partition. It then divides the cumulative sum by 31, which neatly divides the events into 31-day buckets. You can then take the first episode in each 31 day bucket.

Comment: Correct. Obviously, there are neater ways to do this, but I think this is pretty universal and not too complicated to grasp :-)

Comment: it's not universall at all. As starting point, `datediff` and `isnull` functions are not standard in all engines (in oracle `nvl`, in db2 `datediff` doesn't exists...)  The same for `cte`. . .  Your query is nice, but it's not sql standard. Because there is no sql standard for this kind of queries.